# Does extracting a YouTube MP4 URL counts a new view to the video

Tags: android, ios, xcode, youtube, youtube-api

I am making an iPhone and Android app that plays YouTube videos, and I am using some third-parties libraries (LBYouTubeView, OpenYoutubeActivity,...) that extracts the YouTube MP4 link, so the video playing will be more easier for me and not using web-views.

My question is if I used these libraries does the views count increase for videos or not? Like is just as playing the video from YouTube page?

Comment: Google has its own Youtube apis to work on it. You could have look at that one. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will not increase the view counter. 
It's javascript on the youtube.com/watch page counting the views.

Also the view counting algorithm youtube provides is more complicated. They are kind of verifying every view.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the YouTube Terms of Service explicitly state you cannot access the stream directly, or use any player except the approved players:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

II.10:

"Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to ... access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly authorized by YouTube"

The libraries you mention are not expressly authorised, and may be considered a breach of the YouTube Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is very ambiguous about how views are counted.  From the [docs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en-GB):

> Video views are algorithmically validated to maintain fair and positive experiences for content creators, advertisers and users.

Video views are only counted from the official player (embed plays) and plays on YouTube's site.  If your script to scrape the URL from the manifest doesn't load the player, then you can pretty much guarantee that extracting the video file from a YouTube URL will not count as a play.